# Call Log and SMS permissions policy

Tags: android, google-play

I got a mail Google about new SMS or Call log policy, according to this I’m not able to use READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS anymore in my app. My 5 apps has been removed.

I’m using these permission for Panic feature i.e. to send SMS in background in case of panic.

Or Send Auto SMS to know user by checking the contact id from received SMS in case user is busy in meeting or is at silent zone area.

Is there any solution for this above problem?

Comment: Did you asked Runtime permission for Call & SMS?

Comment: Yes this is a policy change at Google play store. SMS is not considered as core function of your app and will not be allowed. My app is delisted too.

Comment: @GowthamSubramaniam Yes

Comment: @Gkapoor You've to submit a form with a proper reason why you using SMS in your app. If you fill the form and submit it. Google will validate it and respond to you soon.

Comment: @AIMINPAN Did you find any solution?

Comment: Solutions: 1 give up play store and publish it somewhere else. 2. if you can influence google to change their policy... which seems hard :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : You must have to [read this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en)

Long Answer for **Alternatives to common uses:**

## **SMS OTP & account verification**

> With the [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview), you can perform SMS-based user
> verification in your app automatically, without requiring the user to
> manually type verification codes, and without requiring any extra app
> permissions.
>
> If the SMS Retriever API is not an option for your app, users can also
> manually enter a verification code.

## **Initiate a text message:**

> With the SMS Intent, your apps can initiate an SMS or MMS text
> message.

## **Share content:**

> With the Share Intent, your app can enable users to share content or
> send invites through a variety of supporting apps without requiring
> sensitive app permissions.

## **Initiate a phone call:**

> With the Dial Intent, your app can specify a phone number and open the
> phone app. The user can then explicitly initiate the phone call.
>
> The Dial Intent doesn't require the CALL_PHONE permission.

Hopefully you will got answer.

Comment: How the auto SMS will initiate i.e. without user interaction?

Comment: Check that https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

Comment: Suppose If I have to send SMS to contact list number or to contact from which I received a SMS, without user interaction, then how that will happen?

Answer (score 0):

now you may have to use 3rd party API like :- https://www.nexmo.com/ for achieve that's like functionality.